# Filter using GCP console in datastore for a "Key"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore, gql

I know how to query for other fields from GCP console, but how can I query for the `Name/ID` column .

I tried providing `id` by selecting `Key` as per the image below which gives error, I tried GQL as

```
SELECT * FROM KIND_NAME WHERE __key__ = key(Name,'45***')
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM KIND_NAME WHERE __key__ = key(Name,'id=45***')
```

I referred [this link of GCP](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6365503?hl=en)

**How can I query for the `Name/ID` column**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing the case and I successfully filtered by NameID using the following Query by GQL:

> SELECT * FROM [KIND] WHERE **key** = Key([KIND], '[NAME]')

Please note that if the value of the NameID is a self-set, you need the single quotation marks (‘ ‘), whereas if the value is auto-generated ID you don't and it will look like:

> SELECT * FROM [KIND] WHERE **key** = Key([KIND], [ID])